# Google Keyword Tool sample code in C#

Tags: c#

I am interested in writing a small windows application for [Google Keyword tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none) in C#. Just wondering anybody could give me a sample code or some pointers to move in the right direction

any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this. I've been looking all day at the API. I've no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some working samples here
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not written any programs using the Google Keyword Tool, but as far as I understand it Keyword Tool is a part of Google AdWords and Google has an API for AdWords online at http://code.google.com/

My suggestion would be that you start by poking around there.